# Is there anyway a return statement can contain an if, elif conditionals without the else at the end?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been trying to find the answer everywhere but I can't seem to find it. I want to be able to return a statement in my function with an if and (an) elif/s but without an else (just for learning purposes). I am aware that you can do something like this:

```
def my_func(s):
    return "a list" if type(s) == list else "a string" if type(s) == str else "not list or string"
```

The above shows how python allows you to have an if, as many elifs and an else, but is there any way to be able to have an if and (an) elif/s without the need of an else at the end?
Something to note is that I am speaking about having it on the same line as the return statement, not an expanded one checking on multiple lines.

Comment: ... so *what should the function return in case of the missing `else`*? When you say "on the same line" you are basically saying you want a *conditional expression*, this is distinct from the `if-elif-else` *statement*. Expressions *must* return a value, so you must always address this `else` case. But yes, I also agree, just from a style perspective, this shouldn't be one line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is single line you can have:

```
def f(x):
    if x > 10: return 10
```

and you do not (explicitly) have a `else` keyword being used.
Note that this cannot be chained.
Note also that this is anyway equivalent to:

```
def f(x):
    return 10 if x > 10 else None
```

as any function not returning explicitly otherwise will just return `None`.

---

If you consider multi-line constructs, please note that you can do something like:

```
def f(x):
    if x > 10:
        return 10
    elif x < -10:
        return -10
```

which does not have an explicit `else` but is equivalent to both:

```
def f(x):
    if x > 10:
        return 10
    elif x < -10:
        return -10
    return None
```

and:

```
def f(x):
    if x > 10:
        return 10
    elif x < -10:
        return -10
    else:
        return None
```

---

So, all in all, there is not much value in **not** having an `else` at the end or not using the `a if condition else b` expression.

It is probably not ideal for readability to chain multiple `if-else` expressions anyway. Just use multiple lines and enjoy the readability of the code.

---

If your sole concern is to know if the *conditional expression* requires `else` as part of the Python grammar, then the answer is: Yes it does. See the relevant [PEP308](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0308/) for more info.

Comment: Yes I was aware of the first block of code in your answer but that, like you said, can't be chained without any more elif/s on the same line because that block of code is essentially the same as having the if on one line and the `return 10` indented in it.

Comment: @CodingGrind If the question is solely about *conditional expression*, you need to have a `else` and that is it.

Comment: @norok2 Oh, okay thanks for the updated answer though.

Answer (score 2):

No it's not possible. See the language [specs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) and the corresponding [pep 308](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0308/)

In case of return just add `return something if condition else None`

Answer (score 1):

As noted, this is a "conditional expression". Expressions always have to resolve to an object but without the `else` this expression would not. `else None` is reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

You can write the same idea using return inside the if statement
'' if (type(s) == list): return ....''

Comment: That doesn't allow to do `elif`s

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about that :)

Answer (score 0):

In `return x`, `x` is an [expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#expressions) which has to be evaluated to some object, no matter what. So you cannot omit the `else` part of the [ternary operator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) (that's why it's called ternary and not "ternary or binary" ;-) ). That being said, you could shorten your code:

```
def my_func(s):
    return {list: "a list", str: "a string"}.get(type(s), "not list or string")
```